# Main page: slideshow, Sub page: background-image

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, slideshow

How can I add a slideshow (background slider) only to the main pages body (first li)? I want static background images for the sub pages.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://previews.123rf.com/images/tigatelu/tigatelu1310/tigatelu131000075/22731618-Nettes-Schwein-Cartoon-Lizenzfreie-Bilder.jpg);
  background-origin: content-box;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Main Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We haven't been given enough details to solve your problem.

Comment: I would go with this ==> https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

Answer (score 0):

why you didn't try [carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) ? just set the slider button to `display:none;`

Comment: How can I set carousel as a background slider only to the main page?